# How to Convert This jQuery Code to Simple Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am trying to convert this jQuery Code into Vanilla JavaScript code. But I am unable to do.

```
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/$('a#password_here').attr('href', 'url_here').text('password_here').attr('style', 'visibility:visible!important;opacity:1!important;position:relative!important;z-index:1!important;font-size:14px!important;color:#fff!important;');
setInterval(function () {
    if (!$('#password_here').length) {
        window.location.href = 'url_here'
    }
}, 1000)/*]]>*/</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the element using `elem = querySelector(selector)`.
Instead of `attr` use `setAttribute`.
Instead of `text` use `innerText`.
For each style do `elem.style.camelCase='value'`.
Then finally check `elem.value.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your current jQuery code was working, mine should work as well. The line which tests `!$('#password_here').length` seems to be checking whether such an element exists, so I've converted it to vanilla JS. However, if the intention is to check the length of the content, you'll have to use my alternate code on that line (see the comment).

There's a lot about your code that is questionable at best:

It's not clear why you have two different selectors: `a#password_here` and `#password_here`. I'm assuming they refer to the same element, since IDs must be unique on a page. That's why I'm selecting `a#password_here` once, and using that variable in the `setInterval()` callback rather than selecting it again in the callback.

Even more strange: why do you need to check for the existence of an element repeatedly in `setInterval()`? Is some other process occasionally adding the element you're looking for? And why are you redirecting if it's not found?

```
<script>
let a = document.querySelector('a#password_here');
a.href = 'url_here';
a.innerText = 'password_here';
a.style = 'visibility:visible!important;opacity:1!important;position:relative!important;z-index:1!important;font-size:14px!important;color:#fff!important;';

setInterval(function() {
    if (!a) { // Might intend to say a.innerText.length instead
        window.location.href = 'url_here'
    }
}, 1000)
</script>
```